# Using jQuery to apply a style to only even elements (2, 4, 6, etc.) within a div?

Tags: jquery

I want ot apply a style to some elements within a div:

```
<div id="showcase">
 <div class="project">
 <div class="project"> <!-- add a style here -->
 <div class="project">
 <div class="project"> <!-- add a style here -->
 <div class="project">
 <div class="project"> <!-- add a style here -->
</div>
```

The project divs are Wordpress posts so I can't just add the class in the div. So I think jQuery is the way to go.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('.project:odd').addClass('myclass');
```

http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

For optimal performance you should do:

```
$('.project').filter(':odd').addClass('myclass');
```

As James pointed out (and the docs above) `:odd` is used instead of `:even` because counting is `0` based.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that `:odd` is used, and not `:even` because element indexes are 0-based.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/uAZgm/

```
$('#showcase .project:nth-child(even)').addClass('new');
```